# how to rearrange order of ArrayList in Kotlin based on property of the object?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have `ChatMessage` class like the code below:

```
class ChatMessage(val uid: String, val text: String, val fromId: String, val toId: String, val timestamp: Long) {}
```

it has `timestamp` as its property

I have an empty list like this, later I will populate this messageList with the data:

```
val messageList = ArrayList<ChatMessage>()
```

and I want to rearrange that `messageList` based on the timestamp, so the lowest timestamp will be in the index 0 of that array.

how to do that in Kotlin ? I am sorry if this is trivial, I am new in programming and in Kotlin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use sorting function from **Kotlin standard library**.

Let's say, your `messageList` need to sort based on the timestamp then use following syntax below:

```
val sortedList :List<ChatMessage> = messageList.sortedBy { chatMessage :ChatMessage -> chatMessage.timestamp }
```

Above piece of code will return you sorted `List<ChatMessage>` which you can further use.

Find out more **[here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html)**.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sortedWith` with `compareBy` like this:

```
val sortedList = messageList.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.timestamp }))
```

You can even sort by multiple properties:

```
val sortedList = messageList.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.timestamp }, { it.fromId }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Kotlin

1) You can omit the curly braces for a class if they are empty, also your `ChatMessage` seems to be a good fit for a data class:

```
data class ChatMessage(val uid: String, val text: String, val fromId: String, val toId: String, val timestamp: Long)
```

2) You could create a container which you use to collect all messages in an ordered `PriorityQueue`, especially if you only need it ordered. This could look like this:

```
class MessageContainer {
    private val messageList = PriorityQueue<ChatMessage>(Comparator { c1: ChatMessage, c2: ChatMessage ->
        c1.timestamp.compareTo(c2.timestamp)
    })

    fun addMessage(msg: ChatMessage) = messageList.offer(msg)
    fun getAllMessages(): List<ChatMessage> {
        val ordered = mutableListOf<ChatMessage>()
        while (!messageList.isEmpty()) ordered.add(messageList.remove())
        return ordered.toList()
    }
}
```

Now if you insert objects of `ChatMessage` via `addMessage`, they will be ordered in the queue directly and when you invoke `getAllMessages`, you receive an ordered `List<ChatMessage>`:

```
val container = MessageContainer()
repeat(20) {
    container.addMessage(ChatMessage("text$it", (10L..10_000L).random()))
}
container.getAllMessages() //will be ordered
```